# making a helper like laravel defaullt request helper

Tags: php, laravel

i want to make a helper function that i use it widely in my project almost any where or some other helper functions that maybe used now as an example i have laravel request helper in mind like below :

```
request()->get('name);
```

now i know that any where in blade or controller or elsewhere if i use it it works .
now i have 2 questions .
1-how to make a helper like this that does something and can be used easily and widely
2-is that wise to make some helper like that ???

Comment: 1) Here's the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php) for Laravel's helpers, that should give you a good place to start. 2) Helper functions can be very useful and are used extensively throughout the Laravel framework, so I'd say it's wise to use them when appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make global helpers, you can do it like so.

Add a php file (not class) to the following the following path `app/Helpers/helper.php`.

```
if (! function_exists('helper')) {
    function helper() {
        return new Helper();
    }
}
```

To make it similar to `Laravels`, the approach is to make an object you can call methods on the initial helper call will return.

```
class Helper {
    public function getHelp() {
        return 'did this help?';
    }
}
```

Now get composer to autoload your file with the helper function.

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/Helpers/helper.php"
    ]
}
```

This will enable you to call the following.

```
helper()->getHelp(); // returns: did this help?
```

For your last question.

> Is is wise to make some helper like that?

In object oriented design this is an anti pattern as it deals with global functions and should be either static namespaced calls or objects. However in the context of `Laravel` i really enjoy what you can do with these helpers and right now, in my current project, we have global functions dealing with formatting floats to our locale money string representation that have helped a lot and is very pleasant to use.

Comment: thanks man that really helped alot but some one else is answered too i find ur answer more complete but that got my eye too which is more like laravel structure i accep ur question and wished could accep both but i have to research more about that i think :)

Comment: It is two different approaches and both are correct, the most important part is just learning new things and becoming better :)

Comment: Actually this answer is more in line with the question which is how to make a helper function like ```request()```. My method is slightly different and more in line with Laravel's helper classes e.g. ```Str``` or ```Arr``` etc. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers Both methods should work fine and be pretty much interchangeable. Not sure if there's any performance implications?

Comment: @justrusty exacly the point i am looking for is the performance issues that if any of them got any performance issue or no .

Comment: Without knowing the exact i could not imagine any of these solutions, would impact performance in a real life scenario. Else people would avoid using Str:: methods. and the function solution is as barebone as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Create a helper class in `app\Helpers\GlobalHelper.php`

```
<?php


namespace App\Helpers;


class GlobalHelper
{
    public static function helloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World"
    }
}
```

Then in your `config\app.php` in the aliases array add

`'Helper' => App\Helpers\GlobalHelper::class,`

Then in a blade file you can use `{{ Helper::helloWorld() }}` or in a controller you can use `\Helper::helloWorld();`

Comment: Actually did not thought of this approach nice one!